# Caching the parent view model with children view models in zend framework 2

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework2, viewmodel

I am trying to cache the Parent view model having 3 children view models in Zend Framework 2. Each view model is attached with different template files. When I  tried to cache the parent viewmodel , it cached only its own template but not included the contents of its children.

In the code given below; I tried to cache the every action method returned viewmodel from the module.php by event listener as 
                                                                                                `$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, array($this,'saveActionCache'), 0);`

```
     public function saveActionCache(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $match = $event->getRouteMatch();
    if(!$match) {
        return;
    }

    if($match->getParam('actioncache')) {
        $viewManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('viewmanager');

        $result    = $event->getResult();
        if($result instanceof ViewModel) {
            $cache = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('text-cache');
            // Warning: The line below needs improvement. It will work for all PHP templates, but have
            //          to be made more flexible if you plan to use other template systems.
            $renderer = $viewManager->getRenderer();

            $content = $renderer->render($result);
            // here we can see the the $content is the only content of the
            // parent viewmodel template and it is not including its child
            // viewmodel contents
            $cacheKey = $this->actionCacheKey($match);
            $cache->setItem($cacheKey, $content);
            $tags = $match->getParam('tags');
            if (is_array($tags)) {
                $cache->setTags($cacheKey, $tags);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the template for your parent model are you outputting each child model? (for an example of what I mean, see [this example from the ZF2 docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#nesting-view-models))

Comment: Why do you cache on `EVNET_RENDER`? If you take `EVENT_FINISH` you can easily grab the contents of the response. Example is the [SlmCache](https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmCache) module (not production ready!)

Comment: Yes,  I am outputting the each child model

Comment: Thank you Jurian, EVENT_FINISH has  fixed the problem.